# Counting the number of concurrent users on a page

Tags: asp-classic

We have a very active web page which has lots of ajax and regular updates via jquery.  It can load a huge amount of data (< 100k per minute) every user in peak situations and we had 2,000 people online during the last peak.

What we would like to do is count the number of concurrent users. If over 500 (and not a registered user) then bad luck, hit the road!

Has anyone got a class or some other process? Our server recycles every hour so I am thinking of an application level variable that adds one to the current count if successful (gold users are exempt from the test but are added to the quota so we may have 600 users).

Has anyone else played with this idea?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some ideas...

```
application.lock()
application('visitors') = application('visitors') + 1
application.unlock()
```

You should stress-test this solutions up to the numbers you want to allow. It will probably work is my fair guess.

Consider counting the ajax url page instead, that gives a more accurate estimate of the load. When going for session's you will not know when I've left. Counting via the Ajax line gives a more accurate number of visitors.

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about the ajax side of things and I will focus my attempts down this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion: in GLOBAL.ASA on Session OnStart you could increase count of running Sessions in some global (Application) variable.
Do not forget to decrease it in GLOBAL.ASA on Session OnEnd

Comment: session_onend fires when session timeout occurs (Standard 20 minutes) so you will hav a timespan where the user is no more on the site and the session actually ends

Comment: Also this counter would be for the entire application and not a specific page. Unless you incremented or decremented the counter on page load and page unload. Even then, that's a lot of locking and unlocking the application variable and might cause the application to suffer in performance.

Comment: counting:application.lock